# Best Practice for adding columns to a Table in Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, data-modeling

I came across a scenario where there is a column need to be added in a table. What is the Industries best practices to add a column to the existing table in Production System.

1. By default at the end
2. At appropriate position
3. Before the Audit fields of the table

Our data modeler has added the column and chose the default options. Is there any performance hit if the added column is used frequently.

What is the efforts to develop the script that always add the column before the audit fields as a standard?

Any help will appreciated.

Comment: To add a column anywhere but the end you have to rename or back up the original table, create the new structure, and import the data back.  Not fun...  Unless you have a VERY compelling reason to have the column in the middle, put it at the end and use views or other mechanisms to reposition the column.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible in Oracle to decide position of the new column. (well, unless you drop and recreate new table).
Note, that order of columns is not related to performance issues.

Comment: Mostly yes, The order of columns has almost no effect on the performance. But if a newly added column causes row chaining/migration, there will be small performance degradation if we have mostly NOT NULL last column(s) and mostly NULL column(s) before it/them. The order of columns will affect storage more than performance. So consider putting mostly NULL columns last.